# Should I really not use the word 'bossy'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I know for a fact that the word "bossy" is quite controversial and could be somewhat problematic in some situations?

Since I'm not a native speaker I don't fully get the nuance of this word. I thought it was just "boss" + "-y" so I found it so useful to use in everyday conversation at first. But I saw quite a lot of people in my country (whose first language is not English of course) say you should never use the word.

But then I heard Ariana Grande's song *Moonlight* where it goes:

> He's so bossy, he makes me dance-

And now it's so confusing? Because I know that the singer is also a  passionate feminist. So my question is, should I avoid using the word "bossy" no matter what?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? Please do so if you haven't already and edit your question to mention what you found and still don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: Of course you can use the word. It's a word that's used all the time. You just need to use it in the right context. But you haven't provided any context for your confusion. (Aside from a song lyric, which shouldn't be something that determines its normal use).

Comment: @Laurel The nuances he's talking about are not mentioned in any dictionary.

Comment: I tidied your post up a bit. If you want to avoid your question being closed, I'd suggest adding in any sources you can find online that talk a little about this

Comment: @ab2 please post that comment as an answer!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

'Bossy' means that one is acting in an arrogant manner, more of a caricature of a boss, acting like people should do what they suggest (when in fact they do not have 'boss' status). (which is to say a bossy boss is probably not a likeable boss, but you should probably do what they say. a bossy person who is not your boss is just annoying).

The word 'bossy' is a little informal, but it has the same taboo status as, say, 'fat'. That means it doesn't have any taboo status as is, but if you call someone that, or refer to someone as that and they hear it, it is usually in a negative direction. The word is most appropriate to describe a situation where one person, who is a colleague, makes a suggestion (or more than one) in an expectant manner.

Also, in the past 10-15 years or so (probably longer), its use in the US at least has become somewhat problematic as it has accrued a nuance of disparagement particularly against women. That is, when used for a woman, it has the feeling that for the supposed exact same characteristics a man would be called 'having leadership qualities'. Using 'bossy' likely shows a double standard. Other examples might be a man called 'headstrong' but a woman 'bitchy'.

It would not be *as* disparaging currently to call a man 'bossy' because it wouldn't have the double standard overtones. But for a woman it is (certainly nowadays) considered disparaging.

Just as the word 'fat' has no taboo (unlike 'bitch' or 'shit'), 'bossy' has no taboo, but you're advised in US culture not to call someone fat or bossy to their face. Well, that's a little too flat. 'Bossy' is a tiny bit taboo.

In non-native contexts, saying 'you should never use this word' is a bit strong.  There are similar words, like 'hysterical' or 'shrill' or 'spinster', which have both a female and disparaging connotation and may be taken badly. You probably shouldn't be using any of these words for a woman, but they're not nearly words that would be bleeped out/censored in the media.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because I didn't know that the word had acquired gender-specific pejorative tendencies. Some words, such as _biddy-like_ and _schoolmarmish_, are inherently gender-specific; others, like the noun _scold_, owe their sexism (to some extent) to old technical usage (in the case of _scold_, the term was used in eighteenth-century statutory law to refer to certain behavior by women). But I've always thought of _bossy_ as being primarily a child's word, used in the context of other (usually older) children, regardless of gender. Thanks for the interesting discussion, Mitch.

Comment: I agree with @SvenYargs, "bossy" is often used by children, addressed to other children. In Britain, children say "bossy boots". In the USA, a common childhood protest is, "You're not the boss of me."

Comment: Feel free to incorporate these references into your answer: http://banbossy.com/ and https://money.cnn.com/2015/10/15/technology/sheryl-sandberg-grace-hopper/index.html

Comment: Adding to the confusion for non-native speakers is the fact that in recent years, a new common use-case for "boss" and "bossy" has developed, primarily via social media / meme sharing (skewing towards the young *but **not** restricted exclusively* to young people)  in which people will say in boast: *"Doing XX like a boss!"* where XX can be a range of different activities or tasks - leading to a non-pejorative use of "boss" or "bossy" which is similar in some ways to other "reclaiming of pejorative phrases": the *appropriate positive use case* is extremely tightly restricted and abstruse.

Comment: @GerardFalla Minor changes to words can affect meaning considerably. 'Boss' and 'bossy', while sharing a lot about being a boss, have very different uses and connotations. I'm limiting myself here to simply 'bossy'.

Comment: I'm with you here, but the reason it's relevant is the OP's mentioning of the pop-culture reference: "...He's so bossy, he makes me dance..." which undoubtedly borrows from the currency of "boss" as a desirable trait in limited contexts in that specific social milieu...

Comment: @GerardFalla I have never heard "bossy" be used to mean "like a boss."

Comment: User227026, lyrics, like poetry, are very subtle to interpret. Sometimes they're metaphorical, or ironic, or joking, or all sorts of things. But here I suspect it is the usual "verbally pushing people around".

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer! It was really helpful. I have anther question. If a man says "Oh I was too bossy.", is it still problematic or, is calling themselves bossy okay?

Comment: Like @AzorAhai, I've never (in the UK) come across *bossy* as meaning *like a boss*. Instead *boss-like* or even *boss-ish* could be used (they're rare enough that I'd keep the hyphen in both).  As an aside, [*like a boss"](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/like-a-boss) doesn't always mean *like a boss* in a literal sense

Comment: *"That is, when used for a woman, it has the feeling that for the supposed exact same characteristics a man would be called 'having leadership qualities'."* Can anyone direct me to any actual evidence of this? I've seen this claim asserted so many times that people just take it as truth, but never in my encounters with this claim did they present any empirical evidence.  In fact, I've seen at least a couple of studies that suggest the exact opposite -- that women get await with being more "bossy" and getting less judged for it. However, these studies could possibly be wrong.

Comment: @user227026 I think "I was too bossy" for oneself is OK male or female (like I said it's not a taboo word and is OK under some circumstances. It is a little informal, and like others have mentioned has a bit of a childish connotation. In quite another direction, I would suggest since all these are questions you have about the word you should refrain from using it yourself because it is easy to misuse.

Comment: @Eff What kind of empirical evidence would be satisfactory to you? I don't question your skepticism, but I think this issue is not easily answered behaviorally (by taking video of people in natural setting using the words and recording their biological responses, things like slapping them in the face or heightened heart rate). It is a reflective thing, using words, people telling us their emotions about it. And there is ample data about how people feel about it (google 'bossy hysterical'). Note that there is a difference between an experiment about the word 'bossy' and one about leadership.

Comment: @Eff There is always a difficulty in relying on self-reporting/introspection and whether people agree based on recognizing the same feeling or just sympathizing.

Comment: @Mitch Well, scientists can often be smart and develop ingenious ways to test things. So there may be many types of experiments that could convince me. However, I know of one experiment done. They had two amazing actors (1 male + 1 female) give real talks from politicians (which included snarky language, bossyness, arrogance, etc), with body language and everything. They had a number of people respond to questionnaire's about their reactions to the speeches. What they found was that when the actor was female, people responded much more positively to her bossyness. They found the male smug.

Comment: @Mitch As I said, I don't make any firm conclusions based just on this study (or the others that I know). I'm simply saying that I've seen several studies (which are by no means perfect) that point to the exact opposite conclusion compared to what is popularly said. What I'm also saying is that when people claim that women are unfairly judged for being bossy, I have never seen them provide anything resembling empirical evidence. That does not mean, necessarily, that the evidence doesn't exist. But they didn't provide any.

Comment: @Mitch I can tell what you *won't* convince me, though. It must be a study that compares similar behavior. Just the fact that people respond negatively to "bossy" women is not convincing, because it may be that their reaction is completely justified. A study that shows that a greater percentage of people find their female bosses "bossy" (measured by any reasonable definition) is not satisfactory, because it may truly be that male and female bosses behave differently.

Comment: @Elf Sure, those experiments on social cues and perception are about leadership. qualities. They are not about the word 'bossy' which is the subject here, which would require a different experimental design. There's a big difference between a word and the situations it might be applied to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82778/discussion-between-eff-and-mitch).

Answer (score 5):

Bossy woman here.

["Bossy"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bossy) is a colloquial, and respectable, term for a cow, but I know that isn't what you are asking!

It isn't fair, but I advise you never to call a woman "bossy" if you want to remain on good terms with her -- even if, **especially if,** she **is** bossy.

If you are a woman, and you know the woman very well, and you both belong to a set whose members jokingly refer to themselves as bitches and similar words, you can get away with it...but this is ultra informal.

If you are a man, don't, ever. It will sound as though you are putting the uppity woman in her place.

More generally, a good rule of thumb is: if you aren't a native speaker, be very careful -- as you know -- about using potentially offensive terms unless you are willing to burn your bridges.

Comment: I thought that was *Bessy*.  Maybe it's an AmE/BrE split?

Comment: @RonJohn: I assume your comment is referring to it being a "colloquial name for a cow"? If so, I agree; I'd say "Bessie" is a stereotypical cow's name; "Bossy" is not.

Comment: @V2Blast read all the definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary link provided by ab2.  One of them (surprisingly, it says "US INFORMAL") is *a cow*.

Comment: Ah, I see it on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bossy#Etymology_2): "(US, informal, dated) A cow or calf." According to the etymology listed there: "Diminutive of dialectal English *boss*, as used in the term *boss-calf* (which, like *buss-calf*, is a variant form of *boose-calf*, a calf kept in a *boose* (“stall”))." It's not an actual *name* for a cow, but rather a dated *term* for one.

Comment: 'Uppity' is another one of those words that has bigoted associations, but rather for African-Americans, at least in the American South.

Answer (score 4):

I might gently chide my pre-schooler child to not be so bossy...if I used it on an adult, I would be pointedly comparing them to a pushy pre-schooler.  It also tends to be a gendered insult: A man and a woman can both behave the same way, but the behavior that is seen as appropriate for a male leader is deemed "bossy" when done by a woman.